# WP Bones - How to check for other plugins on activation of my plugin

Tags: php, laravel, wordpress, plugins

I am new to [WP Bones Plugin Framework](https://github.com/wpbones/WPBones/). I need to check if `woocommerce` is installed on my plugin activation. I can do it in the custom plugin file like this

```
function activate()
{
    if (!class_exists('woocommerce')) {
        deactivate_plugins(plugin_basename(__FILE__));
        wp_die(__('Please install and activate WooCommerce first. Click the Back button in your browser to continue.'));
    }
}
```

But how can I do this check in my plugin while developing in **WP Bones** framework.

Comment: Have you tried adding it inside [https://github.com/wpbones/WPKirk/blob/master/plugin/activation.php](https://github.com/wpbones/WPKirk/blob/master/plugin/activation.php) ?

Comment: Yes I did. Actually opened an issue as well.